# Conducting a Stratified Random Sample (Statewide Poll)

Tags: sampling, stratification

I am interested (in theory) in conducting a stratified random sample of $n$ registered voters from a state which has 150 counties.

If I make all 150 counties my strata, must I conduct a random sample (weighted according size relative to the population) from all of the strata? or, may I select a simple random sample of $k$ strata from the 150 and then conduct a random sample weighted according to relative size of the $k$ strata? If so, how does one determine $k$?

Thank you.

Comment: The answer to your question is "It depends on the final objective".  Here is something to think about If you select a random number of counties, how do you know those counties represent the rest of the state?  i.e. There are urban, suburban and rural counties, you may need to stratify these in order to obtain a representative sample.

Comment: Since the counties may vary substantially in size, the selection of $k$ may be a bad idea.  For example, in Nevada the largest county has 73% of the population and the top two 89%, so missing these mean that your sample is unlikely to be representative.  A better choice could be between (a) sampling directly from the whole population, or (b) sampling from all counties: the latter may help if you want certain types of county-level analysis